# SQL Pulling Families into Temp Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to pull families with the same Housecode into a temp table.  The condition being that each house hold needs to have someone aged 64-80.  The entire household would be pulled if the house met that condition.

Here's what I have:

```
select     [PersonalID]
          ,[HouseCode]
          ,[FirstName]
          ,[MiddleName]
          ,[LastName]
          ,[age]
FROM [database]
where Housecode in (select Housecode from [database] where age between 64 and 80)
order by Housecode asc;
```

This pulls kind of a jumbled mess, any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Database is a very poor table name.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: What do YOU mean by "jumbled mess".  The logic seems correct.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images.